# UIView Animation Blocks vs CAAnimation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation, caanimation

iOS animation experts! What are the pros and cons of each method? I know Apple recommends blocks instead of the old `UIView` animation methods (`UIView` `beginAnimations`, etc), but what about `CAAnimation`? When would you use one method vs the other? Is there a tradeoff in terms of performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1)** There is not much difference in terms of memory expenses between UIView's animation blocks and `CALayers's` `CAAnimation` nor in terms of the objects themselves.

**2)** There are limitations to the type of animations you can achieve with `UIView's` animation, so you might be forced to use `CAAnimation` anyway.

**3)** For those types of simpler animations that UIView can handle, it is usually a simpler API to use than that of `CAAnimation`.

Comment: Thanks! I was kinda hoping for more of a discussion, but I guess this covers everything?

Answer (score 2):

As miamk said, there are limitations to the types of animations you can achieve using the [UIView animateWith] method series. Personally I use CAAnimation, but that is because I am accustom to setting up animations that way. I feel you have more control. I tend to spend a day making a CAAnimation really really fine-tuned and then add it to my UIView extensions class so any view can use it.